# Getting "Connecting over ADB to localhost:5277...failed"

Tags: android, adb, android-auto

Hi all i am trying to launch Desktop Head Unit(DHU) using android ADB.
I have followed all steps what mentioned in [installing DHU](http://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html#test-it-dhu) steps.
But i am getting following error.

[image]

Please some body help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Just follow these steps: https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you perform the following steps:

1. Make sure developer mode is enabled on your phone.
2. Install Android Auto on your phone.
3. Enable developer mode by tapping on the title in the app several times quickly.
4. Once in developer mode, tap on the 3 dot menu on the top corner and click "**Start head unit server**".
5. Connect your device to the computer.
6. On your computer now, enable tcp forwarding via "`adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277`" (if this fails, you may need to call `adb kill-server`). You will need to perform this step any time you disconnect then reconnect your phone to the computer.
7. Start the DHU by calling `desktop-head-unit.exe`

Comment: For developers trying this in 2022, on step number 3, scroll down to the version section and tap on it ten times. This will activate developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

"Developer Mode

Finally, a note about developer mode, since a few people will certainly ask. It's still there and accessible in basically the same way. Instead of tapping several times on the lead image, you'll want to give ten quick taps right on the words "Android Auto" in the action bar. Just like before, a toast message will confirm that it worked. But don't expect anything new in the developer options screen, it's identical to the previous version."
[AndroidPolice](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/04/android-auto-v1-4-cleans-up-the-companion-app-interface-and-adds-granular-control-for-previously-connected-cars-apk-download/)

Enjoy your Android car development ;)

Answer (score 0):

First connect your phone to computer then open android auto on your phone click menu icon(you need to enable developer mode on app first) click start head unit server.Try to open DHU on your computer.