# Android Auto DHU + ADB: ...failed to resolve: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: android, adb, android-auto

I am trying to test an app in Android Auto, and I'm setting up the desktop head unit.  I have followed the directions - the phone is in developer mode and the Head Unit Server is running.  I also have the DHU on my host macbook, but I cannot get it started.

```
$ adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277
5277
$ ~/.../desktop-head-unit
Connecting over ADB to localhost:5277...failed to resolve: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
Failed to start Google Automotive Link.
```

Sometimes it is associated with the DHU window appearing, but being entirely solid black, and my mac doing the spinning beachball thing. Other times I see nothing at all appear.

As far as I can tell, adb is trying to connect but the DHU possibly isn't specifying a host. A similar error message appears if I try and use `adb connect` without specifying a host.

I have also tried `adb reconnect`. `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server` before rerunning the commands. I also tried `adb install` to see that installing an apk still works, and it does.

Comment: A possible solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34023421/3442842

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#running-dhu